# What is the maximum length for an Android application name?

Tags: android

My android application name is three words long, but when I put it in phone it becomes two words long. How to solve this?
I saw many application with three words example: "Advanced Task Killer"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The max length a name displayed under an icon in either the home screen or apps list will depend on device and user settings. The name in the Settings->Manager Applications list will usually be longer, but again depends on certain factors.

Answer (score 19):

A short app name for display on the device menu (**12 character max including spaces between** ) and a longer name for the App Store or Android Market (**30 character max, recommend 20 including spaces  between**).

Comment: "12 character max including spaces between " is not true for all devices

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't matter what's on your screen; Google sets the rules. The limit is 30 characters.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en#details

Comment: As of June 2017 it is increased to 50 characters

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to the question. The OP is asking about their app name being cut off. They didn't specify but the only place this happens is the home screen. Their app name is well under 50 characters so it's obviously not about the maximum allowed name; it's about what will actually display.

Comment: If the op wanted to know about screen rendering, they could've asked that. People are going to be stumbling across this page wanting to know the answer to the question exactly as phrased, without those extra details − that question was "what is the maximum length?"

Comment: As of July 2023, the limit has been decreased to 30 characters (though likely this change was made some time previously)

Answer (score 7):

#### 2019's answer

**Android**: 50 characters

[image: android character count limit]

**iOS**: 30 characters

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It does not become two word long as you say but gets wrapped around and possibly get clipped. There is no limit per-se on the application name size however beyond a certain length it would ellipsize on the device.

For Instance, app name "Thisismybigname" wil show as "Thisismyb.." while
"This is my big name" might show as "This is "

Comment: How to solve it.should i think about another name? or  can i show three words by any method.

Comment: There is no issue to solve, for three words make sure your words are small and concise with ascending order priority for each word. I would rather prefer having a shorter name if that is a requirement. An app is more recognizable by its icon than by its name as you can have multiple apps with same name.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found out how a different app name displayed in PlayStore compared to the app name in app drawer on phone can be achieved:

The app name in PlayStore is defined in the developer console webpage of the app at parameter

```
Title = "This is my long app name"
```

The app name at the phone (e.g. app drawer) is defined in the Manifest of the app and here at the definition of the main activity:

```
<activity android:name="demo.MyActivity" android:label="ShortAppName">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

My app is listed on play store as **General Engineering Free**. after trying for hours to show the word "Free" in the application launcher icon you can do up to 25 characters in ONE word.

i fixed it like this: **General_Engineering_Free** .

it can also work like **GeneralEngineering (Free)**.

Answer (score 0):

based on experience a short app name for display on the phone's menu/home

**(8 character max including spaces between)**

and a longer name for the App Store or Play Store

**(30 character max, recommend 20 including spaces between).**