# What is the application label character limit?

Tags: android

What is the character limit for the application label defined in the manifest file?

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7823996/1214469

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no set limit that's documented or that I'm aware of.  I just created and installed an app with an android:label longer than 500 characters.

There's of course a practical limit - about what a given GUI will actually display to a user.  That varies, but as there are many single English words that would fade out before the end on my tablet's display, you might focus more on your icons, and on a name that will read well on the Android Market, than on the abbreviated text that a user will see below the icon that he's looking for.

Comment: Thanks Julian, I also had a brief look at the Android source and there doesn't appear to be any checks on the length.