# Will all android devices display the same length app name?

Tags: android, google-play, galaxy

I wonder if all Android devices display the same length app name. I made an app and can see it's full 27 characters name on my Galaxy S4. How will the same name look on older phones/versions of Android? Will they display less characters of the app name than my S4? If so, how many will they display and is there an amount of characters all phones will display?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the name of the app length has changed with different releases of Android. But different sized devices might struggle more depending on how you're displaying your text. There are a couple threads on this subject.

Here's one: [how much long can be a android application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823996/how-much-long-can-be-a-android-application-name)

EDIT: You could test with an emulator on a very old device.