# Android application name more than 10 letters

Tags: android, eclipse, namespaces, letters

My Android app name is 11 letters long. No spaces between the letters.
While the ninth letter continues letters are transferred to the next line.

How do I make all the letters appear in the first line?

Comment: Found this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222335/use-shorter-home-screen-app-title-so-that-it-doesnt-get-truncated and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823996/what-is-the-maximum-length-for-an-android-application-name

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. 
It depends on android launcher. 
i.e on some devices like samsung which use custom Samsung launcher you can not have this problem and on some devices with different luncher you can, because it is depends on android launcher.

Comment: Thank you
But the same device (Android smartphone, Huawei g510) other applications with the same number of letters is not the problem.

Comment: Numbers of lethers but for example wwwwwwwwww has more width then iiiiiiiiii it depends on width which is set in launcher app